# using the find function and the exec flag

Tags: bash, find, exec

This is noob question:
I'm trying to run the following script that I found online:

```
find <file name> -type f -exec cat {}
```

for some reason I'm getting an `find: missing argument to '-exec'` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon (quoted or escaped) at the end of line is missing. It should be:

```
find <file name> -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still nothing... nevermind, it's working!

Comment: perhaps, if your shell interprets `{}` in some special way, quote it, like `'{}'`